# Upload Files directly to S3 chunk-by-chunk using Play Scala using Iteratees

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, playframework-2.0

I have tried in vain to upload files directly to s3 using Iteratees. I am still new to functional programming, and finding it hard to piece together some working code.

I have written an iteratee which process chunks of the uploaded file and sends them to S3. The upload fails at the end with an error.

Please help me fix this.

Below is the code I came up with

Controller Handler

```
  def uploadFile = Action.async(BodyParser(rh => S3UploadHelper("bucket-name").s3Iteratee() ))  { implicit request =>
    Future {
      if(uploadLogger.isInfoEnabled) uploadLogger.info(s"Contents of Uploaded file :: \n " + request.body)
      Ok(views.html.index("File uploaded"))
    }
  }
```

Helper Class

```
case class S3UploadHelper(bucket: String, key: String = UUID.generate()) {

  private val AWS_ACCESS_KEY = ""
  private val AWS_SECRET_KEY = ""
  private val yourAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)
  val amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(yourAWSCredentials)


  private val initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, key)
  private val initResponse = amazonS3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest)
  val uploadId = initResponse.getUploadId

  val uploadLogger = Logger("upload")

  def s3Iteratee(etags: Seq[PartETag] = Seq.empty[PartETag]): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Either[Result, CompleteMultipartUploadResult]] = Cont {
    case in: El[Array[Byte]] =>
      // Retrieve the part that has not been processed in the previous chunk and copy it in front of the current chunk
      val uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
        .withBucketName(bucket)
        .withKey(key)
        .withPartNumber(etags.length + 1)
        .withUploadId(uploadId)
        .withInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(in.e))
        .withPartSize(in.e.length)
      if(uploadLogger.isDebugEnabled) uploadLogger.debug(">> " + String.valueOf(in.e))
      val etag = Future { amazonS3Client.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartETag }
      etag.map(etags :+ _)
      Await.result(etag, 1.seconds)
      s3Iteratee(etags)
    case in @ Empty => s3Iteratee(etags)
    case in @ EOF =>
      import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
      val compRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, key, uploadId, etags.toList)
      val result = amazonS3Client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest)
      Done(Right(result), in)
    case in => s3Iteratee(etags)
  }

}
```

Although the Iteratee seems to work and I am able to process the file chunk by chunk, the upload fails with a weird error. Here are the logs

```
[debug] upload - >> [B@1df9048d
[debug] upload - >> [B@152dcf59
[debug] upload - >> [B@7cfeb0d8
[debug] upload - >> [B@136844c5
[debug] upload - >> [B@16f41590
[debug] upload - >> [B@6dd85710
[debug] upload - >> [B@64294203
[debug] upload - >> [B@35366c2f
[debug] upload - >> [B@358a78c
[debug] upload - >> [B@2c171020
[debug] upload - >> [B@20076fb
[debug] upload - >> [B@4d13580
[debug] upload - >> [B@42738651
[debug] upload - >> [B@5671082f
[debug] upload - >> [B@57c70bb4
[debug] upload - >> [B@4154394f
[debug] upload - >> [B@4f93cf15
[debug] upload - >> [B@4bac523f
[debug] upload - >> [B@eaec52e
[debug] upload - >> [B@6ed00bf5
[debug] upload - >> [B@3f6a8a5d
[debug] upload - >> [B@16fe1a25
[debug] upload - >> [B@6e813a61
[debug] upload - >> [B@e01be7
[debug] upload - >> [B@6bb351c4
[debug] upload - >> [B@dfa51a5
[debug] upload - >> [B@6acf2049
[debug] upload - >> [B@6a7021d4
[debug] upload - >> [B@1b3c602f
[debug] upload - >> [B@44146d94
[debug] upload - >> [B@574ac037
[debug] upload - >> [B@3cdf258b
[debug] upload - >> [B@441a0727
[debug] upload - >> [B@2385aafd
[debug] upload - >> [B@224f9dc2
[debug] upload - >> [B@6779077d
[debug] upload - >> [B@734e178a
[debug] upload - >> [B@7d92895c
[debug] upload - >> [B@23edaaa1
[debug] upload - >> [B@c00134e
[debug] upload - >> [B@ff1a703
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 98h72s0EBA7653AD, AWS Error Code: MalformedXML, AWS Error Message: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema, S3 Extended Request ID: R7e44g8oRy5b4xd7MU++atibwrBSRFezeMxNCXE38gyzcwci5Zf
[error] application - 

! @6k2maob49 - Internal server error, for (POST) [/v1/file_upload] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[AmazonS3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.10-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.10-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.10-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.10-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:556) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.3.11.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:289) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.3.11.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:170) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.3.11.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2723) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.3.11.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.completeMultipartUpload(AmazonS3Client.java:1964) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.3.11.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this in past, Amazon s3 needs 5Mb chunks, I was returning tuple at last, you could change as per your requirement.

```
val client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key, secret_key))

def my_parser = BodyParser { 

val consume_5MB = Traversable.takeUpTo[Array[Byte]](1024 * 1024 * 5) &>> Iteratee.consume()
val rechunkAdapter: Enumeratee[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = Enumeratee.grouped(consume_5MB)

multipartFormData(Multipart.handleFilePart({

  case Multipart.FileInfo(partName, file_name, content_type) => {

    val object_id = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "")
    val object_id_key = if (content_type.getOrElse("").contains("video") || content_type.getOrElse("").contains("audio")) object_id else object_id + file_name.substring(file_name.lastIndexOf('.'))
    var position = 0
    val etags = new java.util.ArrayList[PartETag]()

    val initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, object_id_key)
    val initResponse = client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest)
    println("fileName = " + file_name)
    println("contentType = " + content_type)

    (rechunkAdapter &>> Iteratee.foldM[Array[Byte], Int](1) { (c, bytes) =>
      Future {
        println("got a chunk!  :" + c + " size in KB: " + (bytes.length / 1024));
        val is = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)

        val uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
          .withBucketName(bucket).withKey(object_id_key)
          .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId())
          .withPartNumber(c)
          .withFileOffset(position)
          .withInputStream(is)
          .withPartSize(bytes.length)

        etags.add(client.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartETag)
        position = position + bytes.length

        c + 1
      }
    }).map { v =>
      try {
        val compRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(
          bucket,
          object_id_key,
          initResponse.getUploadId(),
          etags)
        client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest)
        println("Finished uploading " + file_name)   
        client.setObjectAcl(bucket, object_id_key, com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)
        (object_id_key, file_name, content_type.getOrElse("application/octet-stream")) 
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => {
          println("S3 upload Ex " + e.getMessage())
          val abortMPURequest = new AbortMultipartUploadRequest("xxxxxxx", object_id, initResponse.getUploadId())
          client.abortMultipartUpload(abortMPURequest);
         ("error", file_name, content_type.getOrElse("application/octet-stream"))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}))
```

}