# Scala & Play: stream files to S3 using iteratees

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, playframework, streaming, loops

The idea: create an endpoint that receives a file stream from a client and "forwards" it to S3, without saving it to the disk first.

```
CLIENT ---> Play ---> S3
```

I understand this can be achieved using Iteratees and Enumerators through building a custom BodyParser.

There are a number of questions about this, the two most recent ones being [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603364/upload-files-directly-to-s3-chunk-by-chunk-using-play-scala-using-iteratees) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586997/how-to-use-iteratees-and-enumerators-in-play-project-to-stream-data-to-s3).

Unfortunately none of the existing questions shows an end-to-end solution, from writing the BodyParser to wiring it into an Action endpoint. Anybody can help?

Comment: Which version of `Play` are you using? `2.3.x` or `2.4.x`? The answer also depends on how you get the stream form the client. If you can post some code up to the point that you have a Stream of bytes, it would be much easier to answer. Do you get it by another http call?

Comment: This question as is, is too broad. You should try taking information from the linked questions, put together an attempt, and then come back with a specific question or problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play Iteratees has been moved to a [standalone project](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#Play-Iteratees-moved-to-separate-project) with the latest version of Play 2.6.x. Though streaming files to S3 can be easily achieved by a combination of using [Alpakka](https://github.com/akka/alpakka) S3 connector with Play's [Accumulator](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaEssentialAction).

Details about the Alpakka's S3 connector are available [here](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/s3.html) and for the sake of simplicity and better understanding I've delineated the entire setup with Play Framework in the following article: [Stream a file to AWS S3 using Akka Streams (via Alpakka) in Play Framework](https://www.ubertechblog.com/2018/05/stream-a-file-to-aws-s3-using-akka-streams-via-alpakka-in-play-framework.html).